# Share sheet - exclude options which are not provided as Type Properties in UIActivityType

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios-sharesheet

I want to exclude `Add to iCloud Drive, Add to Reading List, Save to Files & Print` from share sheet.

I could exclude Add to Reading List and Print options using following code. Because these [type properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype) have been provided.

```
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.addToReadingList ]
```

After with when I search google I found a way to remove options which are not included in type properties as follows (Ex: Add to iCloud drive)

```
UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.CloudDocsUI.AddToiCloudDrive")
```

I want to know that how can we find row values to exclude other options which are not defined in [type properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype). For instance Save to Files

Comment: Any updates? i am trying to exclude save to files

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to determine what `UIActivityType` values are used for undocumented types is to add a `completionWithItemsHandler:` block which logs the `UIActivityType` parameter that it is called with. Then use your app to share something and select the activity type that you want to find the value for. The completion hander will be called, logging its type.

Alternatively, you can create your own object which implements `UIActivityItemSource`, add that to the item activities that you are sharing and implement `activityViewController(_:itemForActivityType:)` and log the type.

Comment: I find that I am not successful for excluding certain custom activities using this method. E.g., for google maps, if I use: UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.Maps.ShareTextShareExtension"), which is what I found by this method, I still see google maps in the possible activities.

Answer (score 3):

I tried Geoff's suggestion (logging the `UIActivityType` by implementing a `completionWithItemsHandler`) for my purposes: disabling 'Add to Notes', 'Add Reminder', and 'Save to Files'.  It works EXCEPT for 'Save to Files'.

The logged type of the Save to Files `UIActivityType` is the same one listed in this question, and adding this to the `excludedActivityTypes` does not work as of iOS 11.1.2.  Others ([here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82750), [and here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/263651#263651)) have run into this issue as well.

For the time being it seems there is no way to exclude the Save To Files `UIActivityType`.  Hopefully Apple will update the documentation on how to do so soon.

Comment: Anyone has any update on this, whether apple has addressed the issue?

Comment: @SumitKapadia Any one has update on this question ?